# Incorrect result when using defines in an expression

Tags: c, macros

The order of magnitude is not correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define M_H 1.007975/(6.02214076*pow(10,23)*1000)
#define k_B 1.380649*pow(10,-23)
int main()
{
    printf("%G\n",M_H);
    printf("%G\n",k_B);
    printf("%G\n",M_H/k_B);
    return 0;
}
```

Because it gives:

```
1.67378E-27
1.38065E-23
1.21232E-50
```

And i need that constants as defined.

I used gcc 12.2.1-1 with the `-lm` flags. I was expecting:

```
1.67378E-27
1.38065E-23
1.21232E-4
```

Comment: operator precedence, reminder that macros are just text substitution

Comment: In `M_H/k_B`, do you really want `1.007975 / (6.02214076 * pow(10,23) * 1000) / 1.380649 * pow(10,-23)` or do you want `(1.007975 / (6.02214076 * pow(10,23) * 1000)) / (1.380649 * pow(10,-23))`?

Comment: GERMÁN ORLANDO CUEVA ESTRADA,  Why code `1.380649*pow(10,-23)` and not `1.380649e-23`?

Comment: You macros shouldn't be calling `pow` at all.  It makes no sense.  `pow(10, -23)` is just `1e-23`.  Have you never seen scientific notation before?

Comment: GERMÁN ORLANDO CUEVA ESTRADA, `f*pow(10, p)` risks loss of precision.  Note that `1.380649e-17 != (1.380649*pow(10,-17))`.  Best to form your constants directly.

Comment: Unrelated: The Avogadro constant is 6.02214076E+23. Why do you divide the atomic weight of hydrogen by 6.02214076E+26?

Answer (score 7):

`M_H/k_B` expands to:

```
1.007975/(6.02214076*pow(10,23)*1000)/1.380649*pow(10,-23)
```

Note that the 2nd `pow` is not enclosed in parentheses, and therefore the multiplication is done after the preceding division. You should wrap your defines in parentheses to prevent that:

```
#define M_H (1.007975/(6.02214076*pow(10,23)*1000))
#define k_B (1.380649*pow(10,-23))
```

I'd also recommend you to replace the `pow` function call with the `1e-23` syntax (aka [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)); this way the number in `k_B` will be parsed as a single token, and the parentheses would not be necessary there:

```
#define M_H (1.007975/6.02214076e26)
#define k_B 1.380649e-23
```

> and i need that constants as defined

If, for some reason, you cannot modify those definitions, you can still add the parentheses at the point of use:

```
printf("%G\n",(M_H)/(k_B));
```

Answer (score 1):

do

```
#define M_H (1.007975/(6.02214076*pow(10,23)*1000))
#define k_B (1.380649*pow(10,-23))
```

to ensure correct order